# Order review page goes blank in magento onepage checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

I am using Magento 1.7 community edition and whenever I'm logged in as a customer and try to checkout, the order review tab in onepage checkout returns an empty page. Its working fine when i checkout as guest. I've searched a lot but nobody seems to have this issue. I'm not getting anything in exception or system logs.

Comment: Did you check your Browser JS error console? Can you add a screen shot

Comment: May be, these links could help     http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/83260/P30/

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263320/#t354472

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with some fatal PHP error, encountered by Magento. The reason can be any. Most probably, something is wrong with installed 3rd party extension or custom development, you may made in Magento.

In order to see the actual error, enabled developer mode in Magento. The easiest way to do it is to temporarily edit index.php and change

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Then you will see error, which will let you uncover the problem to fix.

Comment: I turned on the developer mode, still getting the blank html. No error in logs or anywhere

Comment: That's bad, as then nobody here will be able to help you. Install XDebug in PHP, use IDE like PHPStorm or NetBeans and go through the execution with debugger to find, what's going wrong.