# magento One Page Checkout is totally blank

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento.After clicking 'Checkout'  i'm getting blank page.I've enabled ini_set('display_errors', 1)  and increase memory limit to 512M(php_value memory_limit 512M) in magento folder's htaccess.But unable to get any clue.Any idea,Thanks.i'm using magento Version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Have you checked your logs? (Set dev mode on your dev box in index.php) Do you have any modules which hook onto the event that could be killing it?

Comment: 'Price Slider' extension i used in the project.is it killing the process

Comment: Sorry ignore my comment about observer, I thought you were talking about when you clicked proceed. Are you getting a stack trace you need to try get your error messages showing correctly.

Comment: I've enabled  developer mode(Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);)  but still getting blank page.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640216/order-review-page-goes-blank-in-magento-onepage-checkout

Comment: check `var/log/{system.log|exception.log}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36659/discussion-between-input-and-user1987095)

Comment: system.log it showing   "2013-09-02T12:34:54+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/page/1columns-right.phtml" error

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `1columns-right.phtml`, this is not a standard in template in base so you were missing the template in your theme folder, I hope so at least as modifying core files is asking for trouble.

`app/design/frontend/{theme folder}/default/template/page/1columns-right.phtml`

For a temporary fix you could copy `1column.phtml` to `1columns-right.phtml` as one page checkout should work with the default files.